# Correct mat-card-avatar image height in mat-ccard-header

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

As a personal project, I'm building a website using angular for one of my buddies. It may or may not ever go live, but I'm doing the project for my own personal learning. I've been a web app tester for the past five years, but only developed in a handful of situations, so I apologize if I'm incredibly naive or inexperienced.

I have a series of mat-card's that I'm putting information about centres around my province in (address, phone number, etc.) and I want to include each centre's logo/image as the mat-card-avatar. Right now, I have this:
[image]
My HTMLis here:

```
  <mat-card class="centres-card" *ngFor="let centre of centres">
    <mat-card-header fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <div mat-card-avatar>
        <img class="avatar" src="{{centre.img}}">
      </div>
      <mat-card-title>{{centre.name}}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>
        {{centre.streetAddress}}
        <br>
        {{centre.city}}, {{centre.province}}
        <br>
        {{centre.postalCode}}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

My question is, I don't understand why both the header text and content text are overlapping the image, and not being pushed down by it.

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: can you post your total html code?

Comment: This is the entire angular component, what else should I post?

Comment: check it by changing fxLayout = "column"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to get what you're looking for:

- Option **1**: use a `div` with `mat-card-avatar` and set the background
  from you TS array
- Option **2**: use an `img` with `mat-card-avatar` ad set
  the source

You were putting `<img>` inside the `div` with `mat-card-avatar`...

**relevant HTML**:

```
<h2>Option 1</h2>
<div *ngFor="let centre of centres">
    <mat-card class="centres-card">
        <mat-card-header fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"
                [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + centre.img + ')'}">
            </div>
            <mat-card-title>{{centre.name}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
            <p>
                {{centre.streetAddress}}
                <br>
        {{centre.city}}, {{centre.province}}
                <br>
        {{centre.postalCode}}
      </p>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>

<h2>Option 2</h2>
<div *ngFor="let centre of centres">
    <mat-card class="centres-card">
        <mat-card-header fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <img mat-card-avatar src="{{centre.img}}">
            <mat-card-title>{{centre.name}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content>
            <p>
                {{centre.streetAddress}}
                <br>
        {{centre.city}}, {{centre.province}}
                <br>
        {{centre.postalCode}}
      </p>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

**relevant CSS**:

```
.example-header-image {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uswtjp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-overview-example.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense why that wasn't working. My only other question is, the image should be a specific size, right? The documentation for mat-card-avatar doesn't really say what the expected size is.